# How to detect when a security incident occurs

Tags: security, automation, azure-sentinel, zscaler

Just landed a new position where I will be in charge of doing some system integrations and automations in regards to security.  I have never done any integrations or automations so this is my first rodeo. I have the following tools at my disposal:

- ZScaler
- Azure Sentinel
- Microsoft Cloud App Security
- Microsoft Power Suite
- Mcafee EPO

I have been given a list of action items to complete.  A lot of them require responding to an incident as soon as it occurs, which is where I am lost.  So for example, say Zscaler detects an IA infection and we want X and X actions to happen once detected. How do I ensure our systems are alerted immediately after the incident occurs?  I am guessing this is a matter of querying the API, but what is the proper way of setting this up with the tools I have?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We're all programmers here. We may have a hard time tackling your question. You may want to try your luck here: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would send the logs of those security tools to Log Analytics, and could construct KQL queries based on them.

For example after having a custom log source for McAfee EPO, you could create a recurring query such as

McafeeEPO
| where EventType = ThreatEventLog
| extend HostCustomEntity = hostname_s, AccountCustomEntity = username_s, IPCustomEntity = ipv4_s

I used https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/blob/master/Detections/EsetSMC/eset-threats.yaml as an example, you can check for others as well.